# Mysql insert from select followed by Id update of new row into original table

Tags: mysql

looking for a mysql query that will do the following:

Take data from Table1 (`detail_fr`) and insert it into Table2 (`bon_fr`) and then update Table1 to record the Id of the new row into a column.

I tried to do something like this, but it didn't work:

```sql
INSERT INTO bon_fr (prive,Numfr,Codunit,user,tva)
SELECT prive,Numfr,Codunit,user,tva FROM detail_fr GROUP BY Codunit, Numfr
UPDATE detail_fr SET bon*fr = LAST_INSERT_ID*() WHERE bon_fr=0;
```